# how to find correct method in polymorphism in java

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I have 4 small classes below.

```
public class A
{
    protected int _i;

    public A(int i)
    {
      _i = i;
    }
}

public class B extends A
{
   public B(int i) 
   {
     super(i+1);
   }
}

public class D extends B
{
    public D(int i)
    {
      super(i+1);
    }

    public boolean equals (D other)
    {
      return ((other!=null) && (_i==((D) other)._i));
    }
}
```

This is the main code:

```
public class DriverABCD
{
    public static void main (String [] args) {
      D d = new D(1);
      Object d1 = new D(1);
      System.out.println (d1.equals(d));
    }
}
```

The instance variable in the both classes should be set to "3". However, `System.out.println (d1.equals(d));` returns FALSE. Only if I change the equals() method signature in class D to:

```
public boolean equals (Object other)
{
    return ((other!=null) && (_i==((D) other)._i));
}
```

it will return TRUE. But why?

Comment: In addition to the answers in the duplicate question, it is also essential to check the type of `other` in a correct `equals` method, either using `getClass` or `instanceof`.

Comment: This is why you always use `@Override`.